# How to read all the pages from response.content Python reuests.get

Tags: python, api

I am using the following code to access data using rest api. I am able to see the page-0 only. what do I need to do to read all the pages and write into a csv file.

```py
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
returnedData = json.loads(r.content)
```

sample output:

```
{'links': {},
   'deviceHid': 'xxxxxx',
   'name': 'xxxxx',
   'type': 'Float',
   'timestamp': 1604597637671,
   'floatValue': 42.0}],
 'page': 0,
 'totalSize': 320589,
 'totalPages': 1603}
```

I tried the following method but it is throwing 401 error

```
num_pages = returnedData['totalPages']
for page in range(0,num_pages-1):
    r_sanfran = requests.get(url, headers=headers,params={'page': page})
    print(r_sanfran)
```

I really appreciate if you share a solution for this problem in Python. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 401 response means "Unauthorized." You likely need to authenticate by including an `Authorization` header in your request with either a username and password or a bearer token.